# INDIAN Currency Formating in mysql Query for JQUERY Bootgrid Table List

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, currency-formatting, jquery-bootgrid

The following is my current scenario in Bootgrid Table

```
<table id="order_grid" class="table  table-striped" width="100%" cellspacing="0" data-toggle="bootgrid" style='font-size:14px'>
        <thead style="background-color:#337ab7;">
            <tr style="color:#ffffff">
                <th data-column-id="id" data-type="numeric" data-identifier="true" data-visible="false">Id</th>
                <th >#</th>
                <th data-column-id="dc_date">Date</th>
                <th data-column-id="id">DC No</th>
                <th data-column-id="customer">Customer</th>

                <th data-column-id="tot_pcs">Pieces</th>
                <th data-column-id="tot_sqft">SQft</th>
                <th data-column-id="tot_appvalue">App Value</th> 
                <th data-column-id="commands" data-formatter="commands" data-sortable="false">Action</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
    </table>
```

and  its mysql query is as follows

```
SELECT dc_no AS id,
   customer,
   tot_pcs,
   tot_sqft,
   format(tot_appvalue,2) AS tot_appvalue,
   DATE_FORMAT(dc_date, '%d-%m-%Y') AS dc_date
FROM dc_header
WHERE active=1
```

But what i need is Indian currency format.
Example `10,00,00,000.00` for 100000000, but i get `100,000,000.00`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT dc_no AS id,
   customer,
   tot_pcs,
   tot_sqft,
   format(tot_appvalue,2,'en_IN') AS tot_appvalue,
   DATE_FORMAT(dc_date, '%d-%m-%Y') AS dc_date
FROM dc_header
WHERE active=1;
```

Mysql will support for the currency formatter based on locale.Please refer

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/locale-support.html

Comment: Thanks Alot...It Works Perfect..!!